# Install ImageMagick in one folder

Tags: drupal, installation, imagemagick

I want to install ImageMagick binaries on a server in my project folder (/var/www/html/*) and not in /usr/bin. I need the binary for my the Drupal module "ImageMagick".

Anyone has an idea how to do that?

Comment: If it's installed in usr/bin it should be available for your module too. Just call it by executable name, without directory prefix.

Comment: Yes I could, but I do not want to change the apache2 setting "php open_basedir" outside of var/www/html* as a security measure.